# Select records to where there is no image attached

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, select

I'm struggling with this query. trying to select items where there is no image attached/assigned to it.

```
select distinct a.itm_id, a.itm_num, d.att_type from saitem as a
    join saassignment as b on b.itm_id = a.itm_id
    join sacatalogitem as c on c.itm_id = a.itm_id
    join saattachment as d on d.att_id = b.att_id
        where c.cat_id = '307' 
                and d.att_type not like '%application%'
                and d.att_type not like '%text%'
                and d.att_type not like '%url%'
                and d.att_type not like '%image%'
                      order by a.itm_id ASC
```

I filtered out all the other attachment types (application, text, and url). How do I tell sql to select the record in saitem table if it doesn't contain an attachment type %image% in table saattachment? Right now I'm filtering out all the %image% attachment types because I don't know how to properly define to get what I'm looking for...

EDIT:  I am trying to select all records in table SAITEM where there is no linked '%image%' attachment type (Column is att_type) in table SAATTACHMENT. My problem is the att_type column contains different types such as application, text, and url so I can't just write where there is no image attachment.

Sample Data:

[image]

Comment: It is not at all clear what you are asking. Can you clarify your question?

Comment: Porvide some sample data...

Comment: I have added picture of sample data from each table

Answer (score 1):

There are several ways to do it.

One way is to do an ANTI-JOIN

```
    select distinct a.itm_id, a.itm_num, d.att_type from saitem as a
        join saassignment as b on b.itm_id = a.itm_id
        join sacatalogitem as c on c.itm_id = a.itm_id
        LEFT join saattachment as d on d.att_id = b.att_id
               and d.att_type like '%image%'
   where c.cat_id = '307' 
     and d.att_id  is null
```

This takes your INNER JOIN and makes it a LEFT JOIN. It then tests for NULL on the joining field on the RIGHT side

Also this technically only finds any `saassignment` that don't have image attachments which may or may not fit your needs. If you provide sample data or more details about your data you may get a more complete answer